# Media queries para Internet Explorer 8 e 9

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Como fazer o IE 8 e 9 ler as condições do Media Query? Já li alguns docs mas não encontrei nada esclarecedor.

A query esta sendo feita no HTML exemplo e eu não gostaria de aplicar apenas em um único CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1366px)" href="css/1366.css" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Algumas coisas a considerar:

O IE9 tem suporte a *media-query*, mas você precisa se certificar de estar em *standards mode*, ou seja, seu `<doctype>` tem que estar correto, e os devidos cuidados com o html tomados. Notar que o IE9 não respeita *media-queries* dentro de `<iframe>`.

Quanto ao IE8, não há como usar *media-query*. A solução seria por um *conditional comment*, como o do código abaixo, e carregar um javascript específico para resolver o assunto.

Vale lembrar que você *praticamente* não vai ter IE8 em dispositivos móveis, então talvez um CSS simplificado dentro do *conditional comment* já resolva.

Eis o *conditional comment*:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="estilo_ie8.css"/>
... e/ou ponha seu JS aqui...
<![endif]-->
```

Vale uma olhada no **[Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)** para esta finalidade.

Comment: valeu as considerações, vou utilizar o Respond.js e verificar como fica.